# TeXify could not compile

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texify

While trying to create and learn how to use LaTeX, I have encountered this error while trying to build my first document.

> [Compiling C:\Users\wilso\OneDrive\first.tex]
>
> TraditionalBuilder: Engine: pdflatex. Invoking texify...
>
> COULD NOT COMPILE!
>
> Attempted command:texify -b -p --engine=pdftex --tex-option="--synctex=1" first.tex
>
> Build engine: Traditional Builder

I have no idea what this means, however it may have to do with the fact that I do not know how to direct the build to TeX Live as the documents are now different from the given initial instructions. I am using Windows.

Comment: `texify` is a MiKTeX-specific command: do you have it installed? Which editor are you using?

Comment: Don't use texify when you just start to learn latex. It is difficult to debug if something doesn't work and so not a suitable tool for someone new. Run pdflatex directly.

Answer (score 4):

Since you appear to be using LaTeXTools on Sublime, you have to make one change to your settings file to tell LaTeXTools to use TeXLive.

1. Open up the LaTeXTools settings file (**Preferences | Package Settings | LaTeXTools | Settings (User)**).
2. Find the section `"windows"` and inside this block, change the `"distro"` setting to `"texlive"`.

This should stop LaTeXTools from trying to use TeXify.